# jqGrid default checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I made subgrid and want that be checkboxes were checked by default.

```
colModel: [
        {
            name: 'enb', index: 'enb', width: 60, align: 'center', editable: true,
            formatter: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue 'Yes' },
            formatoptions: { disabled: false }
        }]
```

But for some reason this does not occur. I use jqGrid 4.4.4 version. 
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly what you mean under "want that be checkboxes were checked by default". If you use `editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue 'Yes' }` during **editing of existing data** then `defaultValue` will be not used. Only if you **add** new data for example using Add button of form editing then the checkboxes in the Add form will be checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code everthing working fine.

```
        {
        name: 'enb', index: 'enb', width: 60, align: 'center', editable: true,
        formatter: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"1:0"},
        formatoptions: { disabled: false }
        }
```